# Get specific element from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to get result of all `strength` properties in the array for a specific name.

For example, I want to get strength for `pachio` & `hunter` **only**. The expected result should be,

```
['cool kids', 'suck bloods']
```

I only know how to filter one value.

```js
const array = [{
  name: 'pachio',
  strength: 'cool kids'
}, {
  name: 'hunter',
  strength: 'suck bloods'
}, {
  name: 'chloyi',
  strength: 'cute'
}]

const result = array.filter(function(getName) {
  return getName.name == 'pachio'; /*This_need_to_be_fix*/
});

const result2 = result.map((getStrength) => getStrength.strength);

console.log(result2) /*cool kids*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also combine two methods

```js
const array = [{
    name: 'pachio',
    strength: 'cool kids'
  },
  {
    name: 'hunter',
    strength: 'suck bloods'
  },
  {
    name: 'chloyi',
    strength: 'cute'
  },
]


let ar = ['pachio', 'hunter']

let data = array.filter(el => ar.includes(el.name)).map(ob => ob.strength)

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Much clearer on this code. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

You're already using the correct method, `filter()`, you simply need to add another condition to the function to also allow the `name` property value to be `hunter`:

```js
const array = [{
  name: 'pachio',
  strength: 'cool kids'
}, {
  name: 'hunter',
  strength: 'suck bloods'
}, {
  name: 'chloyi',
  strength: 'cute'
}]

const result = array.filter(o => o.name == 'pachio' || o.name == 'hunter');
const result2 = result.map(o => o.strength);

console.log(result2)
```

If the list of allowed names gets longer, then you can use an array to contain them to keep the logic more clear:

```
const targetNames = ['pachio', 'hunter'];
const result = array.filter(o => targetNames.includes(o.name));
```

Comment: I see, thanks for your solutions sir. Will try it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a second search array, if you want it to be more dynamic, e.g from an input.

```js
const searchBy = ['pachio', 'hunter']

const array = [{
  name: 'pachio',
  strength: 'cool kids'
}, {
  name: 'hunter',
  strength: 'suck bloods'
}, {
  name: 'chloyi',
  strength: 'cute'
}]

const result = array.filter(o => searchBy.includes(o.name));
const result2 = result.map(o => o.strength);

console.log(result2)
```

This solution uses .filter like you and Rory have mentioned but adds .includes to check for the match.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering, the next time you ask, please arrange the code with quotation marks where necessary.

A filter returns you all the values ​​that match the condition,
According to what you are asking for, you want anyone who is different from = "chloyi"

so...

```
  const array = [
            {
                name: "pachio",
                strength: "cool kids"
            },
            {
                name: "hunter",
                strength: "suck bloods"
            },
            {
                name: "chloyi",
                strength: "cute"
            }
        ]

        const result = array.filter(function (getName) {
            return getName.name !== 'chloyi'; 
        });
        
        const result2 = result.map((getStrength) => getStrength.strength);
        console.log(result2)
```

Comment: thanks sir for the comment, will do arrange the code with quotation marks next time